# What purpose to use union in struct?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm currently struggling with uart snippet codes from embedded UART program.

Then I came across what I can't undersatnd when I analysing code.

Q1. In case of using "union" in "struct". what is the benefit and what purpose to use like this?

```
#define     __IO    volatile   

typedef struct {
  union {
  __IO  uint32_t RR;
  __IO  uint32_t TR;
  __IO  uint32_t DL;
  __IO  uint32_t RR_TR_DL;
  };
  union {
  __IO  uint32_t DH;
  __IO  uint32_t IR;  
  __IO  uint32_t DH_IER;
  };
} UART_TypeDef;
```

Q2. In case of using "union" in "struct" in "struct". what is the benefit and what purpose to use like this?

```
typedef struct {
  union {
  struct{
    __IO   uint32_t CTRLR0; 
    __IO   uint32_t SSI_COMP_VERSION;  
    union {
    __IO   uint32_t DR;              
    __IO   uint32_t DR0;            
    };
    __IO   uint32_t DR1;            
    __IO   uint32_t RSVD_2;       
  };
  uint8_t RESERVED[0x1000];     
  };
} SSI_TypeDef;
```

Comment: That's certainly a peculiar `union`. Note that `DR` and ` DR0` would have in principle the same value.

Comment: Please quote the manual describing the registers which are represented by that typdef. You will probably find something which can be considered "RR", "TR" or "DL", depending on the situation, followed by something which can be seen as "DH" or "IR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case is basically "aliasing" of the field names. The `UART_TypeDef` type consists of two `uint32_t` fields, the first which can be referred to as any of `RR`, `TR`, `DL` or `RR_TR_DL`. Ditto for the second field, which can be `DH`, `IR` or `DH_IER`.

The second case, `SSI_TypeDef`, is similar in respect to the *inner* unions, consisting of three `uint32_t` fields, `CTRLR0/SSI_COMP_VERSION`, `DR/DR0` and `DR1/RSVD_2` (in all cases, either name can be used for the fields).

But the structure as a whole is sized at 4K, due to the unioning with `uint8_t RESERVED[0x1000]`.

---

The aliasing is useful if, for example, the same underlying field can be accessed as either `RR` or `TR`, depending on context. For example, a device may have different behaviour depending on whether you read or write the location.

Say, for example, that you *write* to a given address (a memory mapped I/O operation) to indicate to the other end that you are read-ready (able to receive data). Further assume that *reading* that exact same location will let you know whether you're able to transmit.

First, let's set up said memory mapped I/O address (say it's at `0xf000`):

```
UART_TypeDef *utd = (UART_TypeDef *)0xf000; // very shifty :-)
```

Now *both* these statement refer to the *same* memory address:

```
int transmitReady = utd->TR; // Can I transmit?
utd->RR = 1;                 // Tell other end it can send.
```

Being able to use distinct names for the same underlying thing can aid readability.

Comment: For understand, Could you let me know some usage of example?